# How to additional fields to AWS cognito signup

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, amazon-cognito

I created an Ionic Mobile application using Ionic AWS starter template. I wish to create a new fields for the signup page for registration . I am not able to add additional fields to the cognito user pools. Is there any way by which I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the **attributes section** inside the **user pool**, there you can choose from the default ones:

*address, birthdate, email, family_name, gender, given_name, locale, middle_name, name, nickname, phone_number, picture, preferred_username, profile, timezone, updated_at, website*

or you can create your **custom fields**.

Here you can read more about your question: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html

Comment: Note that, after creating the user pool, you can't add more attributes. You'll need to create a new user pool.

Answer (score 0):

even though locale is selected at the time of user pool creation, i do not see that it is provided when i print the event(pre signup and post signup) received inside lambda functions.

```
{
 'version': '1', 
 'region': 'us-east-1', 
 'userPoolId': 'us-east-1_*****', 
 'userName': '68bbd562-bd2c-436d-8344-********', 
 'callerContext': 
  {
   'awsSdkVersion': 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown', 
   'clientId': '1tmr5dq3b25nd4kem8jes4orck'
  }, 
 'triggerSource': 'PreSignUp_SignUp', 
 'request': 
  {
   'userAttributes': 
    {
     'email': 'testing1@****.com'
    }, 
   'validationData': None
  }, 
 'response': 
  {
   'autoConfirmUser': False, 
   'autoVerifyEmail': False, 
   'autoVerifyPhone': False
  }
}
```

Comment: locale is not marked as required attribute when userpool was defined. I think the frontend needs to fill locale information in order for that to show up in the event on backend (just my guess at this time)